# Error in bochs-2.3.5 while make in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, bochs

I recently installed Ubuntu 10.04, and have g++ installed (I use 'sudo apt-get install g++').

I want to use bochs-2.3.5 in this system and do this:

> ./configure --enable-debugger --enable-disasm

All seems well. But when I type 'make', the following error message appears:

```
symbols.cc: At global scope:
symbols.cc:137:10: error: ‘hash_map’ does not name a type
symbols.cc:145:1: error: ‘hash_map’ does not name a type
symbols.cc: In constructor ‘context_t::context_t(Bit32u)’:
symbols.cc:152:5: error: ‘map’ was not declared in this scope
symbols.cc: In static member function ‘static context_t* context_t::get_context(Bit32u)’:
symbols.cc:173:12: error: ‘map’ was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [symbols.o] 错误 1
make[1]:正在离开目录 `/home/song/下载/bochs-2.3.5/bx_debug'
make: *** [bx_debug/libdebug.a] 错误 2
```

I searched for a while, they said that I less of STL port, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing part of STL, or `hash_map.h`. You can run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to solve it.

Note: this will install GCC, and with lots of libs, that 99.44% developers will find it to be sufficient to build any softwares.

If it still doesn't work, read http://chanvn.com/?p=139.